# iOS Push Notification can't show in the Notification Bar when the application is active?

Tags: ios, notifications

when I quit my application, if I receive the message, the Notification Bar shows me the reason, but when I launching the application, it just don't show on the Notification Bar, did I do something wrong or missing? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show custom UIAlertView from UIApplication's callback:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Updated: to read: [Handling Local and Remote Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4):

> Let’s review the possible scenarios when the operating delivers a
>   local notification or a remote notification for an application.

- The notification is delivered when the application isn’t running in the foreground.

> In this case, the system presents the notification, displaying an
>   alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound.

...

- The notification is delivered when the application is running in the foreground.

> The application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method (for remote
>   notifications) or application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method (for
>   local notifications) and passes in the notification payload or the
>   local-notification object.